# Use Get-Process incorrectly piped to Stop-Process

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I am trying to stop multiple chrome instances in one row through powershell but get a strange behaviour :

```
Get-Process -Name chrome | stop-process $_
```

Returns an error:

> Cannot link paramter Id because it is null.

But I have 8 processes running, and I can issue a stop-process on the first one.

So I do not understand what's going on. (Windows 7)
Any ideas ?

Comment: `$_` is relevant when you're using `Foreach-Object` to explicitly iterate. You're not doing that, you're piping the input straight, so you shouldn't be using `$_` here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just pipe `Get-Process` cmdlet it to the `Stop-Process` and *omit*  the `$_`:

```
Get-Process -Name chrome | stop-process
```

Comment: Ooo shame on me :)

Comment: Or even simpler: Stop-Process -name chrome